# Water is Visible to outer surface of pipe

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I am Simulating Fluid flow in Blender (See Image). The geometry is imported as .stl (Obstacle, Partial slip=0.6) and water has been added in the tank as fluid. It is a free flow from tank. The current resolution 340 and as in the image the water has been detected at the outer surface of pipe. It is a free flow from tank. The current resolution 340 and as in the image the water has been detected at the outer surface of pipe.
[image]

Comment: Not really sure, but did you try to apply scale on your pipes or possibly inflow object? Possibly make your inflow smaller? just some thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your Response!

Yes, I have applied scale on both objects Piping and Fluid. I do not have any inflow and the tank is just filled with water as the object is defined as a fluid.